# Limits of systems of differential equations.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following system of odes involving a real parameter $\epsilon$ as follows
\begin{equation*}
\frac{dx_i}{dt}=f_i(x) + \epsilon^2g_i(x,y) \ , \ \ \ \frac{dy_j}{dt}=h_j(y) + \epsilon^{-2}k_j(x)
\end{equation*}
where $i=1,2,...,n$ and $j=1,2,...,m$ with $m \leq n$. I am tempted to say that in the limit $\epsilon \to 0$, solutions should satisfy
\begin{equation*}
\frac{dx_i}{dt}=f_i(x) \ , \ \ \ 0=k_j(x)
\end{equation*}
Is this correct?

Comment: Wikipedia (see "Singular Perturbation" entry) refers to the Tikhonov paper [*Tikhonov, A. N. (1952), Systems of differential equations containing a small parameter multiplying the derivative] and says that under*] and mentions that for this to be true some conditions should be met. I think that you should stat from there (also they mention Verhulst's book).

Comment: Please clarify what is given and what is unknown. From the notation if looks like k may be given, in which case you certainly can't conclude it's zero.